# where can I find a place in UAE to publish my story?

Tags: novel, publishing

im writing a story but I need help in finding a place to publish it.

Answer (score 1):

This question is too vague, unclear, and localized for the rest of the world to be able to help you. Your best bet would be to approach the publishers in UAE or, if you do not know how to contact any, then approach that country's government which would certainly have at least some services for the writers to assist in finding venues.